# Python precedence

Tags: python, conditional-operator, operator-precedence

With the following code

```
import sys
print "Hello " + sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else "Joe" + "."
```

And when I run

- `python hello.py`, I get `Joe.` - The `Hello` is missing.
- `python hello.py Nick`, I get `Hello Nick` - The period '.' in the end is missing.

However, when I change the code to cover the ternary operation with `()`, then it works correctly.

```
import sys
print "Hello " + (sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else "Joe") + "."
```

And when I run

- `python hello.py`, I get `Hello Joe.`
- `python hello.py Nick`, I get `Hello Nick.`

Can someone explain why the different behavior when I don't cover ternary operator with braces.

Comment: It is called the [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions); it is **a** ternary operator. It happens to be the only ternary operator right now, but you don't call `+` and `and` binary operators all the time, either.

Comment: This is where `format` helps. `print "Hello {}.".format(sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else "Joe")` :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the [documented operator precedence](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence); the conditional expression has the one-but-lowest precedence, only `lambda` is lower.

You may want to look into the [string format syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) instead of manually concatenating string objects:

```
print "Hello {}.".format(sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else "Joe")
```